# Get all possible conditional pairing (without changing order and without reverse duplicate) from a given string

Tags: perl

Please I need a perl code for all possible examples.

### Notations:

- M=Male
- F=Female
- Male name start with M
- Female name start with F

### Pairing conditions:

- Each pairing must consist of one male and one female.
- Duplicate pairs (including reverse duplicates) are not allowed.

### Input examples and desired output:

1. input:

   ```
   M1-M1-F2
   ```

   output:

   ```
   M1-F2
   ```
2. input:

   ```
   F1-F2-F1-M1
   ```

   output:

   ```
   F1-M1
   F2-M1
   ```
3. input:

   ```
   F3-F4-M1-F5
   ```

   output:

   ```
   F3-M1
   F4-M1
   M1-F5
   ```
4. input:

   ```
   F3-F4-M4-F5-M7
   ```

   output:

   ```
   F3-M4
   F3-M7
   F4-M4
   F4-M7
   M4-F5
   F5-M7
   ```

Comment: Split the string, Use a pair of hashes to remove duplicates then enumerate the possable crosses with a pair of for loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure the original order could be preserved using a Cartesian product, but then I've been wrong before  :-)

Even if the original order was kept, I don't see how the male-female requirement could be achieved.

Here is a solution that preserves the original order.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;

    my %data;
    my $i;
    for my $key (split /-/) {
        $data{$key} ||= ++$i;   
    }
    my @ordered = sort {$data{$a} <=> $data{$b}} keys %data;    

    while (@ordered > 1) {
        my $first = shift @ordered;

        print join("\n",
            map {"$first-$_"}
            grep substr($first, 0,1) ne substr($_, 0,1), @ordered), "\n";
    }
    print "\n" unless eof;
}

__DATA__
M1-M1-F2
F1-F2-F1-M1
F3-F4-M1-F5
F3-F4-M4-F5-M7
```

The results are:

```
M1-F2

F1-M1
F2-M1

F3-M1
F4-M1
M1-F5

F3-M4
F3-M7
F4-M4
F4-M7
M4-F5
F5-M7
```

Update: A combinatorial solution.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;

    my %data;
    my $i;
    for my $key (split /-/) {
        $data{$key} ||= ++$i;   
    }
    my @ordered = sort {$data{$a} <=> $data{$b}} keys %data;    

    for my $i (0 .. $#ordered) {
        for my $j ($i+1 .. $#ordered) {
            print "$ordered[$i]-$ordered[$j]\n"
                if substr($ordered[$i], 0, 1) ne substr($ordered[$j], 0, 1);
        }   
    }
    print "\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Chris, Really very helpful my research thanks again

Comment: @user2502386 Good. Glad to help - hope it is clear for you. I used a hash to record the order the terms occurred in each string. [perlintro variable types](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlintro.html#Perl-variable-types) explains what a hash is.

Answer (score -1):

What you are looking for is called the Cartesian product. See http://lookatperl.blogspot.ca/2012/12/a-look-at-cartesian-products.html